# XMLStarlet: Query for MARCXML

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

The following structure is given for a MARCXML file foo.xml:

```
<record><header><identifier>myID001</identifier><datestamp>2020-10-12</datestamp></header><metadata><marcxml:collection xmlns:marcxml="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
      <marcxml:record>
          <marcxml:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="084">
          <marcxml:subfield code="2">rvk</marcxml:subfield>
          <marcxml:subfield code="a">MG 98092</marcxml:subfield>
        </marcxml:datafield>
        <marcxml:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="084">
          <marcxml:subfield code="2">bk</marcxml:subfield>
          <marcxml:subfield code="a">89.52</marcxml:subfield>
        </marcxml:datafield>
        <marcxml:datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="084">
          <marcxml:subfield code="2">ddc</marcxml:subfield>
          <marcxml:subfield code="a">320.9439</marcxml:subfield>
        </marcxml:datafield>
      </marcxml:record>
    </marcxml:collection>
    </metadata></record>
```

I would like to extract only the content of `<marcxml:subfield code="a">` where the previous field `<marcxml:subfield code="2">` contains the string 'bk'.

So the desired output in this example would be: 89.52.

So far, I tried

```
xmlstarlet sel -N marcxml="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" -t -m "//marcxml:collection/marcxml:record/marcxml:datafield/marcxml:subfield[text()='bk']" -v '//marcxml:collection/marcxml:record/marcxml:datafield/marcxml:subfield[text()]' -nl foo.xml
```

which results in

> rvk

> MG 98092

> bk

> 89.52

> ddc

> 320.9439

How can this be done with XMLStarlet?

Comment: Something is not clear: all three `<marcxml:subfield code="a">` meet the requirement, so why is the expected output only `89.52`?

Comment: I would like to select according to certain criteria within '<marcxml:subfield code="a">': ignore if the contained string is not 'bk'.

Comment: Sorry; missed that in the question. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N marcxml="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" -t -v '//marcxml:subfield[@code="2"][text()="bk"]/following-sibling::marcxml:subfield[@code="a"]' -nl foo.xml
```